# Автоматизация скачивания отчетов с сайта

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, download

Мне нужно скачивать много отчетов с сайта (вход с паролем). Все отчеты формируются динамически с помощью JS и сохраняются в формате excel. Документации на этот сайт нет. Как мне сделать скрипт JS (можно расширение для Хрома), который будет скачивать отчеты с нужных страниц (нажимать кнопку скачать, выбирать путь и имя файла и сохранять). Пробовал писать JS код, который находит нужную кнопку на странице и делает клик. Но как выбрать путь и имя и сделать клик внутри окна "Сохранить файл"? Или может есть способ сохранять без отображения этого окна?
Пробовал BrowserAutomationStudio, и всё вроде работает как надо, но смущает безопасность моих логинов и паролей.
Надеюсь услышать какие-нибудь идеи)

Comment: Как вариант можно "вклинится" в код приложения и перехватить сформировавшийся бинарник прямиком из переменной

Comment: С помощью js в браузере вы такое не сделаете. Вы уверены, что отчеты формируются не на сервере?

Comment: Разные отчеты формируются по разному. Но все формируются на сервере.
1. Через асинхронный запрос (приходит json с сервера и конвертируется в exel) 
2.  Ссылка, GET запрос
3.  Через POST запрос (приходит exel файл)
Для первого и второго отчета я смог получить URL адрес.. Для третьего не смог найти. Все ссылки работают только после аутентификации на сайте.
Я немного владею знаниями PHP, JS, HTML, CSS.
Думаю над вариантом написания PHP скрипта, работающим на хостинге (но не знаю как проходить аутентификацию)
Второй вариант - это расширение к Хрому.
И третий - не знаю, может на Java?

Comment: Еще появилась идея! Может использовать local.storage браузера для сохранения всех отчетов. А потом как-то вытащить все отчеты одним архивом в мою папку в файловой системе windows. Это лучше, чем скачивать 100 отчетов кликая по разным кнопкам на разных страницах целевого сайта.

Comment: В идеале, сделать на сервере PHP скрипт, который будет получать отчеты с целевого сайта, авторизуясь, и сохранять их на сервере. Возможно ли такое сделать?